# Styling parent of active element

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <span> content </span>
</div>
```

When I click on the `span`, I am getting an `:active` pseudo class on it so that I can style it. My problem is that I want to style the parent `div` when the child is `:active`.

Is there a way to do this using CSS (I don't think so) or JavaScript?

Two points to note before answering:

1. This question is similar to this except that here the class is not a normal `.active` class, but a pseudoclass `:active`.
2. The HTML provided is just the sample HTML, and I am looking for a general solution which will work for all elements in the page and their parents when they are active, not just these particular items. So solutions like a naive `$('span').click()` handler with a `.parent()` call will not ideally work

Comment: Please see my updated answer (with fiddle)

Answer (score 3):

You could use document.activeElement:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
    document.activeElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor="red";
});
```

I noticed you didn't include the jQuery tag, so this is a native JS approach.

EDIT: Interestingly enough, this doesn't work. For your purposes you can simply use:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
    e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor="red";
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){
    e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor="";
});
```

See a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CEsGH/1/). I'm going to ask a question about this and get back to you on why the former doesn't work.

Comment: +1 for pure JS. I used jQuery because he used it in his own example.

Answer (score 0):

This finds all spans in a page, and creates an onclick event which gives focus to its parent node

```
var allSpans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for(var x = 0; x < allSpans.length; x++) {
    allSpans[x].parentNode.setAttribute('tabIndex',0); // this might not be required
    allSpans[x].onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.focus();
    }
}
```

Check example implementation [here](http://pastebin.com/s5jnMY09)

Comment: .. upvoted the document.activeElement answer as it is a much nicer/accurate solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/13322186/149636